# Tricky CSS conditional sibling > child selector > Can this be done?

Tags: css

In the markup below, I'm looking for a way (perhaps using css selector's) to style the content div differently depending on the presence of menu? Menu may or may not be present in that location in the markup and if it is there, I need to add some top margin to content.

I believe sibling and descendent selector rules might not go this far...

"When menu is present as a child of header set the top margin of content (whose parent is a sibling of header) to 100 pixels. Otherwise, set it to zero"

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="sitetitle">site title</div>
  <div class="tagline">tagline</div>
  <div class="menu">menu</div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="content">content goes here</div>
</div>
```

If css allowed groupings, I would do it this way...

```
(.header ~ .menu) + (.main > .content) {margin-top:100px;}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do that, but then again I've seen some pretty crazy CSS rules.

Comment: The only way you can make conditional selectors is based on pseudo-classes and media-queries... It's quite amazing what you can do with :target and anchors placed before the elements you want to select or even in the beginning of the page.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Not possible in your markup.

CSS selectors can only look at the ancestor and at the sibling axes. You cannot look inside ("what children do I have") - only upwards ("what are my parents") and sideways ("what's next to me").

Examples. This:

```
div.header div.menu
```

refers to any `<div class="menu">` one of whose ancestors is a `<div class="header">`.

This:

```
div.header > div.menu
```

refers to any `<div class="menu">` whose *direct* ancestor (i.e. "parent") is a `<div class="header">`.

This:

```
div.header ~ div.menu
```

refers to any `<div class="menu">` that has a `<div class="header">` among its preceding siblings, i.e. they have the same parent and occur one after another, but not necessarily adjacent to each other (that's "looking sideways").

This:

```
div.header + div.menu
```

refers to any `<div class="menu">` whose *direct* preceding sibling is a `<div class="header">`.

There are no other traversing selectors in CSS (this statement refers to CSS2) and certainly there are no conditionals.

Comment: You can look sideways with sibling selectors

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery:

```
​$('.header:has(.menu) + .main > .content')​.css('margin-top', '100px');​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Unfortunately the `:has()` selector didn't find its way into css3.

But why don't you simply apply a `margin-bottom` to `div.menu`?

Comment: menu is out of the flow (absolutely positioned :)

Comment: I'm trying to make some space above content for the menu, which is absolute positioned in that space. No need for the space if menu is not present.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use some javascript to detect that. Check if menu is under header at load, and if it is, then set the margin-top of content to 100px

Answer (score 0):

I used this CSS code in a conditional formatting.
Format index by counting from the end.

```
#stk-service-account-menu ul li:nth-last-child(1):before {
```